# How to find a string in a dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Upon loading a page I make a database call (via ajax / php) to get a dynamic list. The list displays fine and looks something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#page-bla">bla</a></li>
<li><a href="#page-bla2">bla2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page-bla3">bla3</a></li>
</ul>
```

As soon as the list is done loading I want to dynamically load content based on the page I am on, so I grab the page URL which in this case lets say is bla3. I want to look through the list and grab the URL(href) of the li item containing bla3.

I figured something like this below would work but it does not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').on('load', function(){
        var pageID = $('#menu li a[href$="?bla3"]').attr('href');
        alert(pageID);
    });
});
```

The problem (I am assuming) is that #menu is not loaded quickly enough so the on load event fires before #menu loads, I have tried it with body and that didn't work either. Essentially I just need a away to look through a dynamically generated list after it and the page it is on is fully loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any alert at all? Remove the `?` `$('#menu li a[href$="?bla3"]').attr('href')` should be `$('#menu li a[href$="bla3"]').attr('href')`

Comment: Actually the ? is a typo, but no I am not getting an alert at all. I switched the event from load to hover and aimed it at the li's and it worked fine, so the pageID is correct, the load event is whats not working.

Comment: You would need to add more details to your question, which plugin you are using for the plugin etc... and try to set up a fiddle. is the load event an event provided by the menu plugin that you are using?

Comment: I am using jquery thats it. .on method is part of jquery and the load event is a property of .on. A fiddle wouldn't work (or at least I don't know how to create one) that reflects the dynamic nature of hte content.

Comment: Ahh ok. i dont think there is an element on load event. Yo have document or body on load but not element onload as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="findList()">
```

Then you need this function in your `<head>`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function findList() {
var list = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
var contains = "bla3";
var patt = new RegExp(contains,"g");
for (var x=0;x<list.length;x++) {
  if (list[x].match(patt).length>0) {
    var hrefVal = list[x].childNodes[0].href;
    alert(hrefVal);
  }
}
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, it seems like you're in need of a way to wait for your menu. You can try polling the DOM for the element.

Here's a rough fiddle that seems to simulate what you're describing: http://jsfiddle.net/rkLVx/1/

```
var menuHasArrived = function (fn) {
    console.log('checking...');
    if ($('#menu').length) {
        fn();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            menuHasArrived(fn);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

menuHasArrived(function () {
    alert($('#menu li a:contains(bla2)').attr('href'));
});

setTimeout(function () {
    $('body').append(
        '<ul id="menu">' +
        '<li><a href="#page-bla">bla</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="#page-bla2">bla2</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="#page-bla3">bla3</a></li>' +
        '</ul>');
}, 2000);
```

Good luck